# No output to Map Algebra ArcGIS from script

Tags: python, arcgis, raster

I have issues with the Map Algebra function from ArcGIS.

I have about 200 TIFF files for which I would like to multiply their attributes values by 1000. The script I wrote (see below) seems to work without error, but I don't get any output from it. Why is this?

```
# Import system modules  
import arcgisscripting, os, sys

# Create the Geoprocessor object  
gp = arcgisscripting.create()  

# Check out any necessary licenses
gp.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

# Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox("C:\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Spatial Analyst Tools.tbx")

# Set local variables
inDir = "E:\OriginalDatasetRepertory\VegetationCoverDensity\Grid"  
OutRaster = "E:\OriginalDatasetRepertory\VegetationCoverDensity\MapAlgebra"  

gp.outputCoordinateSystem = "Coordinate Systems\Geographic Coordinate Systems\World\WGS 1984.prj"

for TIFF in os.listdir(inDir):  

    # State the statistical expression
    InExpression = tiff_files * 1000
    print InExpression

    # Set the output name
    OutRasterName = TIFF.replace("LCI_","VC_")  
    print OutRasterName

    # Process: Map Algebra
    gp.SingleOutputMapAlgebra_sa(InExpression, OutRasterName, OutRaster)
```

Answer (score 0):

add print gp.GetMessages() after your map algebra function to see if it gives you any idea what is happening